# Sharepoint 2010 discussion board user creation/authentication for internet (public) sites

Tags: sharepoint-2010

We are creating a internet site (with anonymous access) in SharePoint 2010. One of the features requested is a discussion forum (not anonymous). We very much want to use the built in SharePoint Discussion Board (the look is dull, but we are OK with it). What I don't quite understand is how to implement user authentication and creation. Will every user have that participates in the discussion be a domain user?  If I use a different authentication provider, how do I integrate external roles to SharePoint roles/permissions. Any tips or links on how to implement user management for public SharePoint sites would be great. Thanks.

Similar question, but not what I was looking for:

- [share point 2010 :how to create forum website , using in team discussion question and answerig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6414385/share-point-2010-how-to-create-forum-website-using-in-team-discussion-question)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5098521/any-decent-reference-materials-for-sharepoint-2010-for-internet-sites

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps I didn't search well enough (or didn't use the correct terms) but I eventually found what I was looking for: [SharePoint 2010 FBA Pack](http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/). With this, I am able to create all my users via SharePoint and manage permissions using the role provider. Very easy and powerful solution.